# Creating a HTML form using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to populate a html form using php and mysql. My form should be something 
like below.

[image]

I have tried it, created first two columns of the table. (Category and Grade)
Can anybody guide me to create other 3 columns with input fields.

This is my code so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.id AS cat_id
             , c.name AS category
             , g.id AS grade_id
             , g.name AS grade
        FROM employees e 
        JOIN categories c ON c.id = e.category_id
        JOIN grades g ON g.id = e.grade_id
        GROUP BY e.category_id, e.grade_id"; 

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
//$stmt->bind_param('ss', $todate, $todate);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$numrows = $res->num_rows;
$data = []; 

if ($numrows >= 1) {    
  while (list($cid,$cname,$gid,$gname) = $res->fetch_row()) {
    $data[$cname][$gid] = $gname; 

  } 
}

// prepare output table
$tdata='';
foreach ($data as $categoroy => $grades) {
    $kb = 0;
    foreach ($grades as $id) {
        $kb += count($id);
    }
    $firstb=1;
    foreach ($grades as $id => $grade) {        
      if ($firstb) {
        $tdata .= "<tr><td rowspan='$kb'>$categoroy</td>";
      }

      $firstc=1;            
      if ($firstc) {
        if (!$firstb) $tdata .= "<tr>";
        $tdata .= "<td>$grade</td>";
      }

      if (!$firstb && !$firstc) $tdata .= "<tr>";
      $tdata .= "</tr>\n";
      $firstc = 0;
      $firstb = 0; 
    }
}
```

Hope somebody may help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Tip: you may want to correct the spelling of `$categoroy` to `$category`

Comment: Try to use company_salary_{echo grade_id} as form input names attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you wanted help with for the inputs, but when you get there you will want to construct your inputs something like...

`'<input type="text" name="salary[]" value="' . $curSalaryvalue . '"/>'`

It will be hard to answer the mysql portion of your question without knowing what the data structure of your tables is like.